# How can I check user interaction on android dialog?

Tags: android, session, dialog, ontouch

Android activity has overridden method onUserInteraction.But how can I check the user interaction in the dialog?I want to develop some logic based on this.Please help
This code works (onUserInteraction)fine with Activity
public class MyBaseActivity extends Activity {

```
public static final long DISCONNECT_TIMEOUT = 300000; // 5 min = 5 * 60 * 1000 ms

private Handler disconnectHandler = new Handler(){
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
    }
};

private Runnable disconnectCallback = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Perform any required operation on disconnect
    }
};

public void resetDisconnectTimer(){
    disconnectHandler.removeCallbacks(disconnectCallback);
    disconnectHandler.postDelayed(disconnectCallback, DISCONNECT_TIMEOUT);
}

public void stopDisconnectTimer(){
    disconnectHandler.removeCallbacks(disconnectCallback);
}

@Override
public void onUserInteraction(){
    resetDisconnectTimer();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    resetDisconnectTimer();
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    stopDisconnectTimer();
}
```

}

But how can I use 'onUserInteraction' method with Dialog ?

button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);

            //setting custom layout to dialog
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.cusotm_dialog_layout);
            dialog.setTitle("Custom Dialog");

            //adding text dynamically
            TextView txt = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            txt.setText("Put your dialog text here.");

            ImageView image = (ImageView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.image);
            image.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info));

            //adding button click event
            Button dismissButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.button);
            dismissButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            dialog.show();
        }
```

Comment: what kind of user interaction do you want to register. As this cannot be done in Dialog. If I know what you need, I can help.

Comment: @ShaikMDAshiq I want to register whenever the user is touching the dialogue...Maybe like dispatchTouchEvent

Comment: Have you tried this... http://stackoverflow.com/a/14829365/4192614

Comment: @ShaikMDAshiq yes...I am not able to implement it :-(

Comment: ok wait. I will try and post the code.

Comment: Its seems I am having trouble with it. Sorry.

Answer (score -1):

I have implemented onUserInteraction for DialogFragment.  This has the same handling as Activity for onUserInteraction.  The setUserInteractionEnabled method can also be implemented in an Activity subclass.

```
public abstract class BaseDialogFragment
extends DialogFragment
{    
    protected void onUserInteraction()
    {
        Activity activity = getActivity();
        if(activity != null)
        {
            activity.onUserInteraction();
        }
    }

    protected void setUserInteractionEnabled(Dialog dialog, boolean enabled)
    {
        if(!enabled)
        {
            dialog.getWindow().setCallback(dialog);
            return;
        }

        dialog.getWindow().setCallback(new WindowCallbackWrapper(dialog)
        {
            @Override
            public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event)
            {
                onUserInteraction();
                return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean dispatchKeyShortcutEvent(KeyEvent event)
            {
                onUserInteraction();
                return super.dispatchKeyShortcutEvent(event);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
            {
                if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                {
                    onUserInteraction();
                }
                return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean dispatchTrackballEvent(MotionEvent event)
            {
                onUserInteraction();
                return super.dispatchTrackballEvent(event);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean dispatchGenericMotionEvent(MotionEvent event)
            {
                onUserInteraction();
                return super.dispatchGenericMotionEvent(event);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Call this in your onCreateDialog.

```
public class MyDialogFragment
extends BaseDialogFragment
{
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getContext());

        setUserInteractionEnabled(dialog, true);

        return dialog;
    }
}
```

Note: this will not call onUserInteraction from the dialog's soft keyboard.  That should be handled from a TextWatcher that calls onUserInteraction in afterTextChanged.